# Gender showed null on webpage but I wanted it to display either male or female

Tags: javascript

I want to display gender -- male or female on web page not null.

```
function validate() {
    var fieldsValid = true; 
    var city = document.getElementById("city").value;   
    var state = document.getElementById("state").value;  
    var zip = document.getElementById("zip").value; 
    var gender = document.getElementById("gender"); 
    var prevcourse = document.getElementById("course");

    if(city.length == 0) {
            fieldsValid = false;
            if(!document.getElementById("cityErrMsg")) {
            var errMsg = document.createElement("span"); 
            errMsg.id = "cityErrMsg"; 
            errMsg.appendChild(document.createTextNode("*City is required"));
            document.getElementById("cityId").appendChild(errMsg);
            }
    }
    else {
            var toRemove = document.getElementById("cityErrMsg");;
            if(toRemove){
            toRemove.parentNode.removeChild(toRemove);
            }
    }   
    if(state == "select one") {
            fieldsValid = false;
            if(!document.getElementById("stateErrMsg")) {
            var errMsg = document.createElement("span"); 
            errMsg.id = "stateErrMsg"; 
            errMsg.appendChild(document.createTextNode("*State is required"));
            document.getElementById("stateId").appendChild(errMsg);
            }
    }
    else {
            var toRemove = document.getElementById("stateErrMsg");;
            if(toRemove){
            toRemove.parentNode.removeChild(toRemove);
            }
    }   
    if(zip.length == 0) {
            fieldsValid = false;
            if(!document.getElementById("zipErrMsg")) {
            var errMsg = document.createElement("span"); 
            errMsg.id = "zipErrMsg"; 
            errMsg.appendChild(document.createTextNode("*Zip is required"));
            document.getElementById("zipId").appendChild(errMsg);
        }
    }
    else { 
            var toRemove = document.getElementById("zipErrMsg");;
            if(toRemove){
            toRemove.parentNode.removeChild(toRemove);
            }
    } 
    if(document.querySelector('input[name = "gender"]:checked') == null){
        fieldsValid = false;
        if(!document.getElementById("genderErrMsg")) {
            var errMsg = document.createElement("span"); 
            errMsg.id = "genderErrMsg"; 
            errMsg.appendChild(document.createTextNode("*Gender is required"));
            document.getElementById("genderId").appendChild(errMsg);
        }
    } 
    else {
            var toRemove = document.getElementById("genderErrMsg");;
            if(toRemove){
            toRemove.parentNode.removeChild(toRemove);
            gender = document.querySelector('input[name = "gender"]:checked').value
//this place im not sure if i have to add code to display male or female on a webpage
            }
    } 
    if(document.querySelector('input[name = "course"]:checked') == null) {
            fieldsValid = false;
            if(!document.getElementById("prevErrMsg")) {
                var errMsg = document.createElement("span"); 
                errMsg.id = "prevErrMsg"; 
                errMsg.appendChild(document.createTextNode("*Previous course is required"));
                document.getElementById("prevcourseId").appendChild(errMsg);
            }
    }
    else {
            var toRemove = document.getElementById("prevErrMsg");;
            if(toRemove){
                toRemove.parentNode.removeChild(toRemove);
    }
            addPreviousCourses(); 

    }
    if(document.getElementById("inputDiv")) {
        document.getElementById("inputDiv").remove();
    }

    function addPreviousCourses() {  
        outputCourses = ""; 
        iArray = [];
        if(document.getElementById("asp").checked) {
            iArray.push (document.getElementById("asp").value);

        }
        if(document.getElementById("java").checked) {
            iArray.push (document.getElementById("java").value);
        }
        if(document.getElementById("php").checked) {
            iArray.push (document.getElementById("php").value);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < iArray.length; i++) {
            if(i < iArray.length - 1) {
                outputCourses += iArray[i] += ", ";
            }           
            else {
                outputCourses += iArray[i]; 
            }
        }
    }   

    if (fieldsValid){
    var display = document.createElement("div");
    var city = document.createTextNode("City: " + city);
    var state = document.createTextNode("State: " + state);
    var zip = document.createTextNode("Zip: " + zip);
    var gender = document.createTextNode("Gender: " + gender);
    var prevcourse = document.createTextNode("Previous course: " + outputCourses); 

    display.appendChild(city);
    display.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    display.appendChild(state);
    display.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    display.appendChild(zip);
    display.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    display.appendChild(gender);
    display.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    display.appendChild(prevcourse);


    display.id = "inputDiv";

    document.body.appendChild(display);
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your HTML code, this is more of a guess than anything, but I think I can tell where the issue is... and I'd say that there are actually two issues with it:

1. It seems that you have two radio buttons with name `gender`, but at the top of your code you are reading the value of the element with id `gender`:

   ```
   var gender = document.getElementById("gender");
   ```

   if there is no element with id `gender`, then the variable gender will have the value `null`, that is what you display.
2. Now you may say "Ok, even if I made that mistake, I shouldn't get `null` as I am still updating the value of the `gender` variable in this section":

   ```
   if(document.querySelector('input[name = "gender"]:checked') == null){
       fieldsValid = false;
       if(!document.getElementById("genderErrMsg")) {
           var errMsg = document.createElement("span"); 
           errMsg.id = "genderErrMsg"; 
           errMsg.appendChild(document.createTextNode("*Gender is required"));
           document.getElementById("genderId").appendChild(errMsg);
       }
   } 
   else {
           var toRemove = document.getElementById("genderErrMsg");;
           if(toRemove){
           toRemove.parentNode.removeChild(toRemove);
           gender = document.querySelector('input[name = "gender"]:checked').value
   //this place im not sure if i have to add code to display male or female on a webpage
           }
   }
   ```

   But... are you really? The answer is "no". Let's analyze the code (in pseudo-code):

   1. If there isn't any gender radio button checked

      1. Create and show an error message
   2. Else (there is a gender radio button checked)

      1. If there is an error message:

         1. Hide the error message
         2. Update the value of the `gender` variable

   As you can see, even if you had one element with id `gender` and the variable was initialized to a valid value different from null, **you are never updating the value of the `gender` variable to the value of the checked gender radio button unless you made a mistake first!**.

   The solution is easy: move the update from inside the `if` to outside the `if` (step 2.1.2 to step 2.2). The code would look like this:

   ```
   if(document.querySelector('input[name = "gender"]:checked') == null){
       fieldsValid = false;
       if(!document.getElementById("genderErrMsg")) {
           var errMsg = document.createElement("span"); 
           errMsg.id = "genderErrMsg"; 
           errMsg.appendChild(document.createTextNode("*Gender is required"));
           document.getElementById("genderId").appendChild(errMsg);
       }
   } 
   else {
           var toRemove = document.getElementById("genderErrMsg");;
           if(toRemove){
               toRemove.parentNode.removeChild(toRemove);
           }
           gender = document.querySelector('input[name = "gender"]:checked').value
   }
   ```

And if I'm correct (and again, this is a bit of a guess) that should solve your issue.